# Text zooming similar to 'The Economist' or 'Apple iBooks'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, zooming

Can anyone tell me how could I get the similar zooming like 'The Economist' or 'Apple iBooks'. What may be the technique used to get that performance and look and feel.

I have tried using the html+webview, javascript to get the zooming effect but it is not perfect. :(

Do any one tell me how could we get the same appearance?

Comment: Are you trying to view PDF or web-based content?

Comment: I tried with the UIWebview + HTML, I have used the javascript to zooming and zoom-out. But I am not able to get the similar performance.

Comment: Is the content straight text or are there multimedia elements included?

Comment: text+image, text may be bold or normal,